# how to set border button with 2 colors

Tags: android, xml, button, colors, border

i'm trying to create a border for a `Button` with two color **white** and **black**. So I decide to create a shape. i trying to add gradient with white and black color my code doesn't work

i want  border like this :

[image]

my xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <gradient
                android:angle="360"
                android:centerColor="#000000"
                android:endColor="#bfbfbf"
                android:gradientRadius="360"
                android:startColor="#ffffff"
                android:type="sweep" />

            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:left="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:top="4dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#d2d2d2" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

and  buttn :

```
<Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="OK"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/progress"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/okbtn" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

button_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="@dimen/stroke_width_outer"
                android:color="#000" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="@dimen/stroke_width_outer"
        android:right="@dimen/stroke_width_outer">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="@dimen/stroke_width_outer"
                android:color="#FFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="@dimen/stroke_width_outer"
        android:left="@dimen/stroke_width_outer"
        android:right="@dimen/stroke_width_outer"
        android:top="@dimen/stroke_width_outer">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="@dimen/stroke_width_outer"
                android:color="#7F7F7F" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="@dimen/stroke_width_inner"
        android:left="@dimen/stroke_width_outer"
        android:right="@dimen/stroke_width_inner"
        android:top="@dimen/stroke_width_outer">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="@dimen/stroke_width_outer"
                android:color="#DFDFDF" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="@dimen/stroke_width_inner"
        android:left="@dimen/stroke_width_inner"
        android:right="@dimen/stroke_width_inner"
        android:top="@dimen/stroke_width_inner">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#BFBFBF" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

values/dimen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="stroke_width_outer">3dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="stroke_width_inner">6dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

**stroke_width_inner should be twice of stroke_width_outer always**

Apply background to button -

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background"
    android:text="OK"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

On Layout Editor -

[image: On Layout Editor]

On Device -

[image: On Device]

On Device you won't see the grayish left and top border as you see on Layout Editor

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a good place to use a [**9-patch image**](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html). Any solution based on a regular `.png` file, a `<shape>`, or a `<vector>` will wind up scaling the white and black borders of your button.

Once you've created your `button.9.png` file, then you can set it to be your button's background using `android:background="@drawable/button"`.

### Edit

Here's a 9-patch based on your linked `.png` file:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please look here about creating a shape drawable http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

Once you have done this, in the XML for your button set `android:background="@drawable/your_button_border"`